# get subnet id AWS

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, zsh

i am trying to get the subnet ids within a particular VPC and store them in variables
so I can use them in a bash script

```
aws ec2 describe-subnets --filter "Name=vpc-id,Values=VPCid" --region $REGION --query "Subnets[*].SubnetId" --output text
```

and this gives something like this

```
subnet-12345        subnet-78910
(END)
```

I wonder how I can store them into a variable.

I tried with

```
SBnet=$(aws ec2 describe-subnets --filter "Name=vpc-id,Values=VPCid" --region $REGION --query "Subnets[*].SubnetId" --output text)
```

but then I do not know I can access the array/list created.

I tried with

```
echo $(SBnet[0])
```

but does not work

I am on MACos usin zsh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this as follows (add your VPC and the region):

```
#!/bin/bash

SUBNET_IDS=$(aws ec2 describe-subnets --filter "Name=vpc-id,Values=vpc-1234" --query "Subnets[*].SubnetId" --output text)

for SUBNET_ID in $SUBNET_IDS;
do
    echo $SUBNET_ID
done
```

To split the list of subnet IDs into variables, you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

SUBNET_IDS=$(aws ec2 describe-subnets --filter "Name=vpc-id,Values=vpc-1234" --query "Subnets[*].SubnetId" --output text)

IFS=$'\t ' read -r -a subnet_ids <<< $SUBNET_IDS
echo "${subnet_ids[0]}"
echo "${subnet_ids[1]}"
```

And the individual subnet IDs will be in the `subnet_ids` array.

Comment: thanks, is there a way to store each result in a variable?

Comment: It would be sensible to store the subnet IDs in an array because it's a variable length list. Have added example.

Answer (score 0):

you can do as @jarmod suggested and you could also write a query to extract all the subnets tied to all the VPC's in your system in a comma separated output and use it further like this

```
aws ec2 describe-subnets --query "Subnets[].[SubnetId,VpcId,CidrBlock,AvailabilityZone]" --output text|sed 's/\t/,/g'
```